# How to override parent table style for child table in html?

Tags: css, html-table

I have defined nested table where parent  table don't let to defined new `styles` for child `table`.
Some places in nested `table` I want to hide left and right cell `border`. 
I have tried `border-left-style:none !important; border-right-style:none !important;` for `td` of child table but it not works.

**Edited:**
For parent table styles as

```
table tr td {
                border: 0.1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                font-size: 14px;
                height:21px;
                padding-left:4px;
            }
```

for child table styles as

```
table tr td table tr td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                font-size: small;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }



 table tr td table .btlPropertyAddress td{
            border-left-style:none !important;
            border-right-style:none !important;
        }
```

Where `btlPropertyAddress` added class to child table.

Comment: have a search for css specificity, but to override the child tables styles, your css has to be more specific than the parent styles.  Also if you want us to help you more, you will need to show the styles for the parent table and what you have tried for the child table in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In CSS, when I have lists within lists, I can't override the parent list style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035235/in-css-when-i-have-lists-within-lists-i-cant-override-the-parent-list-style)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? You don't want borders around inner table? you can try something like `table table {border:none}`

Comment: @Aziz, No, I want to hide left and right border for child table cell(not for all rows of child table.)

Comment: @Pete I have edited question and added styles defined for parent table and child table..

Comment: @Aziz, I want to hide the borders around the inner table but your solution does not work.

Comment: @ObiWan not clear, please send a jsfiddle preview and explain how it should look

Comment: @Aziz.  I am mistaken.  Your solution does work after all.